# JupyterLab Extension blueprintjs/core type issue after npm install

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jupyter, jupyter-lab, blueprintjs

1. Made a JLab extension and saved to Git.
2. Created new environment and pulling it works. Confirmed it worked for a friend too.
3. Then just added a new react object to it and saved back to Git in a new branch.
4. Next creating yet a new environment and pulling that code returns the following `blueprintjs/core` issue after npm update and npm installing.
5. Then on a 3rd new environment, running the original code without the react object now also returns the same issues despite it being clean.

```
npm ERR! yarn run v1.21.1
npm ERR! $ jlpm run clean:lib
npm ERR! $ rimraf lib tsconfig.tsbuildinfo
npm ERR! Done in 3.19s
npm ERR! yarn run v1.21.1
npm ERR! $ jlpm run build:lib
npm ERR! tsc
npm ERR! ../node_modules/@blueprintjs/core/lib/esm/components/resize-sensor/resizeObserverTypes.d.ts(2,8): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'type'.
npm ERR! ../node_modules/@blueprintjs/core/lib/esm/components/resize-sensor/resizeObserverTypes.d.ts(2,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
npm ERR! ../node_modules/@blueprintjs/core/lib/esm/components/resize-sensor/resizeObserverTypes.d.ts(2,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ResizeObserverEntry'
npm ERR! ../node_modules/@blueprintjs/core/lib/esm/components/resize-sensor/resizeObserverTypes.d.ts(2,37): error TS2304L Cannot find name 'from'.
npm ERR! ../node_modules/@blueprintjs/core/lib/esm/components/resize-sensor/resizeObserverTypes.d.ts(2,42):  error TS1005: ';' expected.
5 more lines
```

NOTE - I don't use any method from `blueprintjs/core` but it gets npm installed automatically to make a JupyterLab extension to my knowledge, so not sure why this is happening. I tried running older versions of NPM, newer versions of @jupyterlab packages, a specific older version of `@blueprintjs/core`, and nothing seems to work. Please advise.

Version of Jupyter I'm running `@jupyterlab/application=^3.0.0`, `@jupyterlab/settingregistry=^3.0.0`, and `@jupyerlab/notebook=^3.0.0` and `typescript=~3.7.5`.

Was expected it to npm install correctly so I could then build and install my extension locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that my version of typescript was obsolete. Was using ~3.7 and this version of blueprintjs/core needs 3.8+